# Jquery - .click() that doesnt scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm about to make a function on jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header_rules').click(function() {
      // here i define myFunction()
    });
});

<a id="header_rules" href="#">RULES</a>
```

instead of

```
 <a id="header_rules" href="#" onClick="myFunction();return false">RULES</a>
```

But I don't know how to prevent scrolling to the top of the page using jQuery after someone clicks the link.

In fact, I'll total get rid about native JS, which could yield some trouble (that's why I use a JS framework like jQuery).

Any help? Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `e.preventDefault();` where `e` is the first argument of your click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header_rules').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // here i define myFunction()
    });
});

<a id="header_rules" href="#">RULES</a>
```

Comment: Uhm nice. Which is better? `e.preventDefault();` or just the `return false;` ?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` - see my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

The below will also work, but it'll stop other click events on the item, I think.

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header_rules').click(function() {
      // here i define myFunction()
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Returning false also stops the propagation of the event which will most likely not cause issues but is not really necessary and in some cases it can actually cause problems.

Comment: It depends on whether or not you want the click to trigger something else as well.

Answer (score 2):

What ThiefMaster said, and you could also inclue `return false;` inside your function intead of inline.

Comment: He replaced the inline onclick crap with the proper event handler - so he's not inlining anything